# How would i implement random.sample so that it would choose 2 out of 3 variables without it repeating?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a mini quiz that uses classes and OOP. I want to the code to randomly select 2 out of the 3 questions and I don't know whether I should use random.sample or not or where to even use it.

```
import random

class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer

question_prompts = ['What is the capital of England? (a) London (b) Liverpool (c) Glasgow.  Answer(Type a, b or c): ', 'What is the capital of France? (a) Callais (b) Paris (c) Bologne. Answer(Type a, b or c): ', 'What is the capital of Netherlands? (a) Amsterdam  (b) Tilburg (c) Eindhoven. Answer(Type a, b or c): ',]


questions[Question(question_prompts[0], 'a'), Question(question_prompts[1], 'b'), Question(question_prompts[2], 'a'),]


def run(questions):
    score = 0
    answer = (questions)
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
            print('correct!')
```

I want it so that the code chooses 2 out of the 3 questions randomly without it repeating.

Comment: call `run(random.sample(questions, 2)`

Comment: Do you want to implement your own or use something built-in?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) function.

i.e.

```
for question in random.sample(questions, 2):
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> set_of_options = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> np.random.choice(a=set_of_options, size=2, replace=False)
array([2, 3])
>>> np.random.choice(a=set_of_options, size=2, replace=False)
array([5, 1])
>>> np.random.choice(a=set_of_options, size=2, replace=False)
array([1, 2])
```